# Python build from source have error "no module named math", "no module named setuptools" etc

Tags: python, math, module, cygwin, setuptools

i just build python 3.11 (its no matter which version because i have the same problem with other versions) on cygwin and catch this erorr. dyn-load are in PATH - thats ok. may be i need some env to setting up?

I configure it by

```
 ./configure --prefix="/usr" --enable-optimizations
```

Comment: Can you give more detail about how you built it? What do you mean by "catch this erorr. dyn-load are in PATH"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the configuration command you used: `--enable-otimizations` is missing a `p`. In any case, this doesn't tell us very much. Normally when building from source you'll get output about missing libraries that will prevent certain features from being built. Did you see that? Anything relevant to the missing modules?

Comment: Also, what are you doing when you get the errors "no module named math" and "no module named setuptools"?

Comment: Yes you right i miss P) i was trying to run 1 line Hello.py which containg "import math". Also i have problem with running pip3.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably lacking system libraries needed to build Python from source

### Necessary packages

```bash
sudo apt-cyg install python-dev # for math
sudo apt-cyg install python3-setuptools # for setup tools
sudo apt-cyg install build-essential # you probably need this too
```

Comment: OP is using Cygwin on Windows. `apt-get` does not exist there, and packages are likely to have different names.

Comment: Changed to `apt-cyg` not sure if this could work

Comment: Do not use `apt-cyg`. Always use the cygwin `setup.exe` from `cygwin.com`. Check the `Src?` box for each package you want to build. Then you can change to the `/usr/src` folder and then to the source folder for the package and use `cygport` to re-build the package. Adapt this for the next point release. For 3.10, or 3.11 it may be more difficult to adapt the cygport file. You could inquire on the cygwin mailing list for status of the official release of these versions for cygwin. Note that 3.10 is available for MSYS2 and MINGW64.